# Trim first N bases in multi fasta file with awk and print with max width format

Tags: awk, gawk, fasta

**Background**

The multi fasta format contains several record of sequences, each record begins with a single-line description, followed by several lines of sequence (RNA, DNA, protein).  The description line has greaterthan symbol in the beginning, following ">" is the identifier of the sequence, and the rest of the line contains the description of record (both are optional).

in fasta files is common for lines sequences be **formatted to a max width**

input example, with max width="70":

```
>gi|304322925|ref|YP_003856771.1| NADH [Lynx rufus]
MMTYIVFILSTIFVVSFVGFSSKPSPIYGGFGLIVAGGIGCGIVLNFGGSFLGLMVFLIYLGGMLVVFGY
TTAMATEPYPEAWTSNKAVLGMLITGILAELLTACYILKEDEIEVVFKFNGAGDWVIYDTGDSGFFSEEA
MGIAALYSYGTWLVVVTGWSLLIGVLVIMEVTRGN
>gi|295065592|ref|YP_003587393.1| NADH [Nomascus siki]
MTYTLFLLSVILVMGFVGFSSKPSPIYGGLVLVVSGVVGCAVILNCGGGYLGLMVFLIYLGGMMVVFGYT
TAMAIEEYPEAWGSGVEVLVGVLVGLAMEVGLVLWAKECDGLVMVLNFNNMGSWVIYEGEGSGLIREDSI
GAGALYDYGRWLVVVTGWTLLVGVYIVIEIARGN
>gi|295065550|ref|YP_003587316.1| NADH (mitochondrion) [Symphalangus syndactylus]
MTYTLFLLSVILVMGFVGFSSKPSPIYGGLVLVVSGVVGCAIILDCGGGYLGLMVFLIYLGGMMVVFGYT
TAMAIEEYPEAWGSGVEVLVGVLVGLAMEVGLVLWAKEYDGLVVVLNFNNMGSWVIYEGEGSGLIREDSI
GAGALYDYGRWLVVVTGWTLLVGVYIVIEIARGN
```

**My effort**

I wrote a gawk script, it does left trim in sequences (cut first N bases) and if the length of sequence is less than trim then not print it.

```
gawk -v left_trim=15 -v width=70 '
  BEGIN{RS=">"}
  NR==1{next};        #for blank record
  {
    split ($0, a, "\n"); 
    sequence=""; 
    for(i=2; i<=length(a); i++){
      sequence=sequence a[i];
    }; 
    if(length(sequence)>left_trim) {
      printf(">%s\n%s\n",a[1], substr(sequence, left_trim+1));
    }
  }' test.fasta
```

**result**

```
>gi|304322925|ref|YP_003856771.1| NADH [Lynx rufus]
SFVGFSSKPSPIYGGFGLIVAGGIGCGIVLNFGGSFLGLMVFLIYLGGMLVVFGYTTAMATEPYPEAWTSNKAVLGMLITGILAELLTACYILKEDEIEVVFKFNGAGDWVIYDTGDSGFFSEEAMGIAALYSYGTWLVVVTGWSLLIGVLVIMEVTRGN
>gi|295065592|ref|YP_003587393.1| NADH [Nomascus siki]
FVGFSSKPSPIYGGLVLVVSGVVGCAVILNCGGGYLGLMVFLIYLGGMMVVFGYTTAMAIEEYPEAWGSGVEVLVGVLVGLAMEVGLVLWAKECDGLVMVLNFNNMGSWVIYEGEGSGLIREDSIGAGALYDYGRWLVVVTGWTLLVGVYIVIEIARGN
>gi|295065550|ref|YP_003587316.1| NADH (mitochondrion) [Symphalangus syndactylus]
FVGFSSKPSPIYGGLVLVVSGVVGCAIILDCGGGYLGLMVFLIYLGGMMVVFGYTTAMAIEEYPEAWGSGVEVLVGVLVGLAMEVGLVLWAKEYDGLVVVLNFNNMGSWVIYEGEGSGLIREDSIGAGALYDYGRWLVVVTGWTLLVGVYIVIEIARGN
```

**expected**

```
>gi|304322925|ref|YP_003856771.1| NADH [Lynx rufus]
SFVGFSSKPSPIYGGFGLIVAGGIGCGIVLNFGGSFLGLMVFLIYLGGMLVVFGYTTAMATEPYPEAWTS
NKAVLGMLITGILAELLTACYILKEDEIEVVFKFNGAGDWVIYDTGDSGFFSEEAMGIAALYSYGTWLVV
VTGWSLLIGVLVIMEVTRGN
>gi|295065592|ref|YP_003587393.1| NADH [Nomascus siki]
FVGFSSKPSPIYGGLVLVVSGVVGCAVILNCGGGYLGLMVFLIYLGGMMVVFGYTTAMAIEEYPEAWGSG
VEVLVGVLVGLAMEVGLVLWAKECDGLVMVLNFNNMGSWVIYEGEGSGLIREDSIGAGALYDYGRWLVVV
TGWTLLVGVYIVIEIARGN
>gi|295065550|ref|YP_003587316.1| NADH (mitochondrion) [Symphalangus syndactylus]
FVGFSSKPSPIYGGLVLVVSGVVGCAIILDCGGGYLGLMVFLIYLGGMMVVFGYTTAMAIEEYPEAWGSG
VEVLVGVLVGLAMEVGLVLWAKEYDGLVVVLNFNNMGSWVIYEGEGSGLIREDSIGAGALYDYGRWLVVV
TGWTLLVGVYIVIEIARGN
```

**Questions**

- how may i implement width format? i try with `">%s\n%.70s\n"`, print first 70 letters, `">%s\n%70s\n"` print all
- how may i improve this join? exits a function?

  ```
  sequence=""; 
  for(i=2; i<=length(a); i++){
    sequence=sequence a[i];
  };
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your specific questions, you can specify the width of an output field using the `*` format modifier:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{printf "%s\n", "foo"}'
foo
$ awk 'BEGIN{printf "%*s\n", 10, "foo"}'
       foo
```

and no, there is no `join` function to put arrays back together into a string (the opposite of `split()`) BUT if you just let awk split the record into fields instead of you manually splitting the record into an array of elements, then you can just assign a new value to any field and awk will recompile the fields into $0 as I'm doing as a deliberate side-effect in my first solution below when I delete the first field/line with `$1 = ""`.

Here's how I'd approach the task anyway:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { RS=">"; FS="\n"; OFS="" }
NR>1 {
    print RS $1
    $1 = ""
    for ( start=left_trim+1; start<=length(); start+=width ) {
        print substr($0,start,width)
    }
}

$ awk -v left_trim=15 -v width=70 -f tst.awk file
>gi|304322925|ref|YP_003856771.1| NADH [Lynx rufus]
SFVGFSSKPSPIYGGFGLIVAGGIGCGIVLNFGGSFLGLMVFLIYLGGMLVVFGYTTAMATEPYPEAWTS
NKAVLGMLITGILAELLTACYILKEDEIEVVFKFNGAGDWVIYDTGDSGFFSEEAMGIAALYSYGTWLVV
VTGWSLLIGVLVIMEVTRGN
>gi|295065592|ref|YP_003587393.1| NADH [Nomascus siki]
FVGFSSKPSPIYGGLVLVVSGVVGCAVILNCGGGYLGLMVFLIYLGGMMVVFGYTTAMAIEEYPEAWGSG
VEVLVGVLVGLAMEVGLVLWAKECDGLVMVLNFNNMGSWVIYEGEGSGLIREDSIGAGALYDYGRWLVVV
TGWTLLVGVYIVIEIARGN
>gi|295065550|ref|YP_003587316.1| NADH (mitochondrion) [Symphalangus syndactylus]
FVGFSSKPSPIYGGLVLVVSGVVGCAIILDCGGGYLGLMVFLIYLGGMMVVFGYTTAMAIEEYPEAWGSG
VEVLVGVLVGLAMEVGLVLWAKEYDGLVVVLNFNNMGSWVIYEGEGSGLIREDSIGAGALYDYGRWLVVV
TGWTLLVGVYIVIEIARGN
```

or if you prefer:

```
$ cat tst.awk
/^>/ { prtRec(); rec=""; print; next }
{ rec = rec $0 }
END { prtRec() }
function prtRec(        start) {
    for ( start=left_trim+1; start<=length(rec); start+=width ) {
        print substr(rec,start,width)
    }
}

$ awk -v left_trim=15 -v width=70 -f tst.awk file
>gi|304322925|ref|YP_003856771.1| NADH [Lynx rufus]
SFVGFSSKPSPIYGGFGLIVAGGIGCGIVLNFGGSFLGLMVFLIYLGGMLVVFGYTTAMATEPYPEAWTS
NKAVLGMLITGILAELLTACYILKEDEIEVVFKFNGAGDWVIYDTGDSGFFSEEAMGIAALYSYGTWLVV
VTGWSLLIGVLVIMEVTRGN
>gi|295065592|ref|YP_003587393.1| NADH [Nomascus siki]
FVGFSSKPSPIYGGLVLVVSGVVGCAVILNCGGGYLGLMVFLIYLGGMMVVFGYTTAMAIEEYPEAWGSG
VEVLVGVLVGLAMEVGLVLWAKECDGLVMVLNFNNMGSWVIYEGEGSGLIREDSIGAGALYDYGRWLVVV
TGWTLLVGVYIVIEIARGN
>gi|295065550|ref|YP_003587316.1| NADH (mitochondrion) [Symphalangus syndactylus]
FVGFSSKPSPIYGGLVLVVSGVVGCAIILDCGGGYLGLMVFLIYLGGMMVVFGYTTAMAIEEYPEAWGSG
VEVLVGVLVGLAMEVGLVLWAKEYDGLVVVLNFNNMGSWVIYEGEGSGLIREDSIGAGALYDYGRWLVVV
TGWTLLVGVYIVIEIARGN
```

Comment: `$1=""` is only better than `sub(/[^\n]+\n/,"")` because of `OFS=""`. Without that, the assignment would have introduced an undesirable blank char at the start of the line. It's the combination of `$1=""` and `OFS=""` that make the `gsub()` unnecessary - the `$1=""` tells awk to recompile `$0` and `OFS=""` tells it to just remove the newlines (from `FS="\n"`) between the fields during that recompilation instead of replacing them with some other character (a blank by default).